# LDAP configuration in PHP return failed authentication error and success if password is empty

Tags: php, ldap

i am working in a client company and have developed a web system. They requested the system would be able to logged in using LDAP. so i receive this configuration from them:

```
ldap://172.18.100.55:389/ou=EMPLOYEE,ou=COMP,o=COMPENT
```

The user will enter the login details at *index.php* (just a simple html form) and the form will be submitted to *login.php* where the authentication process happen. Here is the code i use at *login.php*:

```
define('LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE', 0x0032);

$ldaphost = 'ldap://172.18.100.55/';
$ldapport = 389;

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");

$upasswd = $_POST['password'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$username = 'cn='.$user.',ou=EMPLOYEE,ou=COMP,o=COMPENT';


if($ldapconn)
{
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,$username,$upasswd);

if($ldapbind)
{
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    ldap_get_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error);
    echo 'Login fail - '.$extended_error;
}
}
```

The company have given me an ldap account to be used for testing. Lets say the test account authentication detail is 
     user ID: **usertest** 
     password: **123456789**

I am pretty much a beginner about LDAP. So i don't really know much on how it works. The deadline is pretty soon so i don't have enough time to do more research. There are 2 things that is really confusing me right now:

1. If i logged in using the user ID and password provided by the company, it shows success, but other user who try to log in will shows this message: "Login fail - NDS error: failed authentication (-669)".
2. No matter what i entered at the user ID field, but if i leave the password field blank, the authentication will always success. I could randomly entered 'sdsdahsvdbhgihuagbi' on the user ID and the authentication will still success as long as i leave the password field blank.

Please,i really need help about this. Thanks in advance

P/S: pardon my english if any

**NUMBER 2 SOLVED**
After some browsing on the internet, i found this:

> An attempt to bind with a blank password always succeeds because the LDAP protocol considers this to be an "anonymous" bind, even though a username is specified. Always check for a blank password before binding.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to use [ldap_set_option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php) to set `LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` to `3` to force it to use LDAPv3 protocol

This should be done after the call to `ldap_connect` and before the call to `ldap_bind`

Update for new information in comments:

It's been a long time since I worked with NDS/eDirectory but Novell have a [TID for this error code](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3335671).

Based on that document, maybe try to get more accounts to test the auth with - either dummy accounts you can use, or real user accounts - if they have just a single person testing your work, it could be an issue with that person's account (that TID mentions an issue with a password containing certain characters) that's causing the issue.

Comment: thanks. im at other company right now. will try it tomorrow and tell you the result

Comment: thanks for your reply the other day. i have set the LDAP protocol version at my php coding. and now i receive error 500. even after removing the set protocol code, i still got this error. basically i need to solve this problem first before i can get it with this one

Comment: hi. i solved the error 500 issues. still got the same problem. i am able to login using the ldap account provided but the employee ldap account receive 'failed authentication (-669)' error